# I am unable to get list of values in the dropdown for input textbox for autocomplete functionality using jquery, node,js and mysql database

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, ajax

following are the code that i have used:

**Html code:**

```
<input type="text" id="empName">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#empName').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, res) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/app",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          term: req.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          res(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
```

**Node.js code**

```
app.get('/app', function(req, res) {
  var q = `select empName from empMasterData as u where empName like ? order by empName asc limit 0, 10`;
  connection.query(q, [req.query['term'] + '%'],
    function(err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      var json = JSON.stringify(results);
      res.send(json);
      console.log(results);
    }
  )
});
```

I am getting only bullets in the dropdown of the text box not the text options for an autocomplete functionality. 
after entering 2 letters in input text box view of the input text box looks like below
.
.
.
.
I am able to see json data in console but not on the screen